# Any lesson learned or best practices on the UX of a 'Download' button?

Tags: website-design, buttons, user-research, research, conversion-rate

My company provides a free edition of a desktop application we developed. Currently I have 'Download' button only on website, and I consider to replace it with one of the following three suggested images I got.

Well I'm not asking what do you think is the best (I know it's not allowed by the forum rules).
I'm wondering if there's any survey or research about that specific issue... any best practices or lesson learned... maybe conversation rates...I'd highly appreciate it.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not saying it's a bad question, but I think this is more of marketing question than a UX question, since what matters here is not ease of use but like you said conversion rates.

Comment: I think you still need to work on the messaging in this button. "Download Free Edition" is kinda confusing, you can instead use FREE TRIAL or "download free trial".

Comment: It's really free edition (with some quantity limitation) but still completely free.

Comment: For sure that white on orange is hard to read and capitals is SHOUTING

Comment: The problem with download buttons is that they look so much like the buttons in ads…

Comment: Just finished some testing with a very similar use of buttons (even colors and shapes, so I imagine where did you get those from). While your specific context may affect the results, try that first one with the arrow and see by yourself

Comment: you can add some text of urgency like "Download Now"

Answer (score 2):

Best practice for "download" buttons is don't make them flashy or look like spam. We're all used to fake download buttons. Make it clean. I'd recommend you use flat design for it so that it stands out from all of the 90's era buttons that are still all over the web to get you to download trojans.

Comment: +1 for bringing in the thought of spam rule which is highly essential

Answer (score 0):

My experience with ecommerce:

- Use big buttons [45-60px heigth] with the company visual;
- if is a Windows 8 desktop application, use the windows store default button, the user will know that is app button and not an ad button;
- avoid using other buttons near this and avoid ads near it;
- keep things clear around the button and the content, it is a flow, the user need acess the page, read the content and click download. Use this hierachy for the page;
- About the moddels it depends of your design, i like the first, but it can be any one, there isn`t a correct for this. Try to do an A/B test, its the best.